# Fibers and they being discrete space

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

When talking about fibers in topology and geometry, especially in fiber bundle, vector bundle and fibration, it is said that they are discrete spaces. But in some diagrams I see, they are often depicted as real lines over base space, which seems to suggest they are not discrete spaces. From what I understand intuitively, discrete spaces are the spaces where all points are isolated, and a real line is definitely not a discrete space. So, are depictions just misleading? Or am I understanding something wrongly..?

OK, so here's the reference to what I am talking about (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition):

> Let X be a topological space.  A covering space of X
>   is a space C together with a continuous surjective map
>
> $p \colon C \to X\,$
>
> such that for every x ∈ X, there exists an open neighborhood U of x, such that
>   p<sup>−1</sup>(U) (the inverse image of U under p)
>   is a union of disjoint open sets in C, each of which is mapped
>   homeomorphically onto U by p.
>
> The map p is called the covering map, the space X is often called the base space of the
>   covering, and the space C is called the total space of the
>   covering.  For any point x in the base the inverse image of x
>   in C is necessarily a discrete space called the fiber over x.

Comment: What reference says the fiber of a fiber bundle is discrete?

Comment: @HenryT.Horton I added reference.

Comment: That's specifically for covering spaces. It's not a feature of all bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fiber bundle with discrete fiber is precisely a covering space. Since the definition you supplied is only talking about covering spaces, there is no contradiction here.

In general, the fiber of a fiber bundle can be any topological space $F$. Just consider the trivial fiber bundle $X \times F$ over any space $X$.